# How to fix Uncaught ReferenceError: TimelineMax is not defined

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

**My JS file:**

```
const logo = document.querySelector("#logo");
const tl = new TimelineMax({});
tl.fromTo(logo, 1, {height: "0%"}, {height: "80%"});
```

**My CSS file:**

```
#logo{
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
position: absolute;
top: 200px;
z-index: -1;
}
```

**My HTML file:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang= "es">
    <head>
        <title>Quark</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="Style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="Limg">
            <img id="logo" src= "Logo.svg">
        </div>
        <script src="animaciones.js"></script> 
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/2.1.3/TweenMax.min.js" integrity="sha512-DkPsH9LzNzZaZjCszwKrooKwgjArJDiEjA5tTgr3YX4E6TYv93ICS8T41yFHJnnSmGpnf0Mvb5NhScYbwvhn2w==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/2.1.3/TimelineMax.min.js" integrity="sha512-0xrMWUXzEAc+VY7k48pWd5YT6ig03p4KARKxs4Bqxb9atrcn2fV41fWs+YXTKb8lD2sbPAmZMjKENiyzM/Gagw==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

And I don't know where the problem is already trying using different versions and nothing

Comment: Import TimelineMax *before* trying to call it, not after

Comment: How can i do that? This could work ? import { TweenMax, TimelineMax} from 'gsap';

Comment: No, rearrange your script tags

Comment: So first I put the TimeLineMax script and then the other?

Answer (score 0):

Move your script tag for timeline max on header

```
<head>
    <title>Quark</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Style.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/2.1.3/TweenMax.min.js" integrity="sha512-DkPsH9LzNzZaZjCszwKrooKwgjArJDiEjA5tTgr3YX4E6TYv93ICS8T41yFHJnnSmGpnf0Mvb5NhScYbwvhn2w==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/2.1.3/TimelineMax.min.js" integrity="sha512-0xrMWUXzEAc+VY7k48pWd5YT6ig03p4KARKxs4Bqxb9atrcn2fV41fWs+YXTKb8lD2sbPAmZMjKENiyzM/Gagw==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 </head>
```

Comment: It worked, thank you very much Ryan, and all people that help me :))